# Where can I find the pZ189vector plasmid vector sequence?

Tags: dna

I need this sequence since it was used in this paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/em.1046. They say that the plasmid was prepared as in this paper http://www.jbc.org/content/271/16/9637/F1.expansion.html (see figure below)
[image]

However, they do not seem to be reporting the sequence of the pZ189 vector. Does anybody know where can I find this sequence?

Comment: Did a search on NCBI and found a list of nucleotides. Maybe you need one of these https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=pZ189

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the sequence is not actually written down anywhere. I asked one of the original authors of the plasmid (not the paper above) and he said that nobody ever did it because at the time when the plasmid was used it would have been a laborious task with little utility. Bummer :(

He also said that plasmid pSP189 is sort of the same but much more efficient and what it does, and is also more studied, with the sequence freely available around the internet.